# Python - pip install markupsafe

Tags: python-2.7, pip

So i want to install markupsafe and get this following error:

```
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\
\users\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-yb_vy0\\markupsafe\\setup.py';ex
ec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'
), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\appdata\local\temp\pip-h
xgnlp-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" f
ailed with error code 1 in c:\users\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yb_vy0\m
arkupsafe\
```

anyone got an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Give a thought to installing [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) which includes `markupsafe` by default.

Comment: You could also try: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#markupsafe

Comment: where do i have to put the .whl file?

Comment: I believe if you double-click it will install from wherever...

Answer (score 0):

you need install [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)  if you are using windows else sudo apt-get install gcc gcc-c++ if is not OS windows